# C# WebClient Encryption - Charles

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, webclient

is it possible to connect to SSL via a web client so that it can not be decrypted later by programs like Charles or Fiddler?

My Problem is, I have a Application white a Login, if the Password and Username from a User is correct, the Server returns Success. But if the user reads the response, he can easily fake it white Charles and „bypass“ my Login.

Comment: I would say no, because Fiddler does a `Man in the middle attack` and reads the stream. You have to encrypt your payload to prevent it.

Comment: @CSharper Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, this is incorrect.  SSL does encrypt the payload... That's the point...

Comment: It already cannot be decrypted unless you explicitly add Fiddler root certificate to trusted and allow it to intercept and reencrypt your traffic. And if you allowed it to do that - then you want exactly this behavior and there is no problem.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark SSL encrypts the payload, but it will use the certificate Fiddler generates, allowing Fiddler to decrypt it, read it, then reencrypt it with the target server's certificate - i.e. perform a MITM attack as C Sharper says.

Comment: @DerRuedi - this feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Please can you clarify exactly what you are trying to protect against so that we can assist you better?

Comment: My Problem is, I have a Application white a Login, if the Password and Username from a User is correct, the Server returns Success. But if the user reads the response, he can easily fake it white Charles and „bypass“ my Login.

Comment: Charles and Fiddler see the traffic as an encrypted SSL stream. They cannot read the payload, and so your secret password is safe from them. They act as a pass-through only. Fiddler can see the raw traffic only if the machine trusts Fiddler's root certificate. E.g. https://docs.telerik.com/platform/knowledge-base/how-to/how-to-trust-fiddler-root-certificate

Comment: @PhillipNgan Charles has a SSL Proxying Mode, if you install the Cert from Charles then you can read the Stream :/

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you are trying to do, and why. Fiddler decrypts traffic by installing a root certificate on your computer, and then uses that basically make a man in the middle attack. Or in other words, with the users permission it subverts the security model of windows. So if you rely on windows to validate the SSL certificate used, there is nothing you can do about it.

If you only have one server that you really want toconnect to, you can validate that the certificate you are getting is the one and only one that you do indeed trust. This is known as certificate pinning.

If you are worried about someone storing the traffic and later using Fiddler to decrypt it, you can stop worrying.